# microsoft luis: why can't i export my app as a json file anymore?

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

i suddenly can't export any app in LUIS(https://eu.luis.ai) anymore. When i mark an app in the app overview or a version in the version overview of an app and click on export, i get first a message, that it is processing the file and then "Download completed successfully", but i don't get any download... where is the file?

Comment: It's working on my side on an old project on eu.luis.ai: got the percent of preparation of the export then "Download completed successfully" and a file downloaded on my navigator (Chrome, Mac OS)

Comment: @rudolf_franek try switching browsers, if you haven't tested already. There is a known bug regarding the export feature in Firefox browsers that the LUIS team has built a fix for and will be pushed in the next deployment. I have just tried in Chrome (Manage > Versions > Check version I want > Export) and it downloads w/o issue